# How to see per user quota limit for gmail api?

Tags: java, rest, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

We are using gmail api to parse latest mails for a few email ids. After few hours of running, we always encounter:

```
{
 "code" : 429,
 "errors" : [ {
   "domain" : "global",
   "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2020-08-25T05:11:14.899Z",
   "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
 } ],
 "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2020-08-25T05:11:14.899Z",
 "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
```

I want to see user rate limit data but the gmail api metrics only show us our app metrics.
I have the email id credentials also with me. Is there any place we can check to exactly pinpoint how much of a surge is causing 429 error? From our app, we are sending about 3 requests/second (message.get, message.list, message.attachment.get, message.modify) as seen from the api metrics we have with us. The per user quota limit is 15000/minute or 250/second and we don't seem to be hitting no where near the limit. Based on this, we can only conclude that the email id has given oauth tokens to multiple apps who are hitting it relentlessly to cross the limit. Now only if we could see why it is happening and adjust our hit rate accordingly to minimize any chance of 429.
Also, if this is not possible then please suggest us a good hit rate/second so that 429 never happens.

Answer (score 1):

### 429 error `User-rate limit exceeded` with `returned with a time to retry` mostly means you are hitting the [Mail sending limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/handle-errors#mail_sending_limits)

Those limits are featured [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852):

> Messages per day: 2,000 (500 for trial accounts)

> Messages auto-forwarded: 10,000

> Auto-forward mail filters:    20

> Recipients per message:   2,000 total per message
> (maximum of 500 external recipients)

> Recipients per message sent via SMTP (by POP or IMAP users) or the Gmail API:  100

> Total recipients per day: 3,000 (2,000 external, 500 external for trial accounts)
> 5 emails sent to 10 different addresses count as 10 unique recipients*
> 5 emails sent to a single address count as 1 unique recipient*

**Those limits are not related to the request rate per minute / second, but to the daily sending limits.** Mind that if you have a trial user, your limits might be well below the ones for paying users.

Both your daily and minute based queries can be verified when you go in your GCP console on `Gmail API -> Quotas` - and select the relevant type from the dropdown.

If it shows that you are below the limit or you are not sure which limits you are hitting, you have the option to contact [GSuite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) for assistance.

Comment: As stated in the post above, message.get, message.list, message.attachment.get, message.modify are used from Gmail api just to read messages and mark them as read. We already have a seperate smtp server to send mails so we don't use the api for that. Please see above and I have also mentioned my rate limits/second above for these functions which I feel are not close to the quota limits to read mails.

Comment: You mentioned your rate limits  per second, but what about the daily mount of calls?

Comment: You mean total calls we make every day? That is around 500,000 calls/day. I don't think that limit is exceeding because if that were the case then all emails for our app would have had stopped working. This is only affecting one email id.

Comment: Do you mean one emailid from which you are sending or to which you are sending? Please check again [those](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852)   It makes a big difference either the emails are addressed to domain internal or external users.

Comment: One email id whose oauth tokens we have. We use it to read mails on behalf of that mail. External entities send mail to that email id.

Comment: Be aware of the fact that those limits apply not only to APIs, but the total Gmail activity. Also if the same token is used in several projects - the quota sums up. You should check the quota of all projects belonging to the user and add it all together. If you still struggle to find the reason - contact GSuite support - they can give you more detailed information about you specific quota consumption.

Comment: I completely agree. Unfortunately, I don't know where to check complete gmail activity for a user.

Comment: You can get some information from the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport/get) querying for [Gmail parameters](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/user/gmail). E.g. setting `parameters` to `gmail:num_emails_sent`.